# Matplotlib max ticks shows first few ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot time series for ~100 days. To improve readability, I want to limit the number of x axis ticks. However, both `plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))` simply show the first few ticks, rather than every n-th tick. The plot below should have ticks equally spread between 05-23 and 07-21 (60 intervals), rather than 6 ticks starting with 05-23

```
plt.stackplot(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:, 1])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel("This axis actually goes from 05-23 to 07-21")
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Data frame used

```
 id   month-day  result
0    05 - 23      78
1    05 - 24     154
2    05 - 25     138
3    05 - 26     176
4    05 - 27     142
5    05 - 28     122
6    05 - 29     199
7    05 - 30     202
8    05 - 31     194
9    06 - 01     166
10   06 - 02     141
11   06 - 03     136
12   06 - 04     108
13   06 - 05     149
14   06 - 06     168
15   06 - 07     182
16   06 - 08     192
17   06 - 09     147
18   06 - 10     133
19   06 - 11     109
20   06 - 12     115
21   06 - 13     124
22   06 - 14     172
23   06 - 15     204
24   06 - 16     131
25   06 - 17     145
26   06 - 18     128
27   06 - 19     179
28   06 - 20     170
29   06 - 21     385
30   06 - 22     427
31   06 - 23     404
32   06 - 24     471
33   06 - 25     334
34   06 - 26     557
35   06 - 27     291
36   06 - 28     337
37   06 - 29     718
38   06 - 30     658
39   07 - 01     524
40   07 - 02     406
41   07 - 03     744
42   07 - 04     941
43   07 - 05     919
44   07 - 06     855
45   07 - 07     740
46   07 - 08     612
47   07 - 09     592
48   07 - 10     797
49   07 - 11     804
50   07 - 12    1072
51   07 - 13    1141
52   07 - 14    1028
53   07 - 15     841
54   07 - 16     822
55   07 - 17    1157
56   07 - 18    1356
57   07 - 19    1031
58   07 - 20    1068
59   07 - 21     992
```

Comment: Can you plz share some data for ease of reproducibility?

Comment: The underlying problem seems to be that the chart you produce has a FixedLocator and a FixedFormatter. Replacing only the Locator but keeping the fixed Formatter will lead to useless results. Try to replace the formatter as well. Or, if you want a working solution you may provide a [mcve] one can work with.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have added a sample dataframe, thanks. Also, I have tried using different plt backends to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem seems to be that the chart you produce has a FixedLocator and a FixedFormatter. Replacing only the Locator but keeping the fixed Formatter will lead to useless results.

Since you are working with dates here, it would make sense to use dates in the plot. You can then use the locator and formatter from `matplotlib.dates`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

df = pd.read_csv("data/month-day-data.txt", sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df["month-day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month-day"], format="%m - %d")

plt.stackplot(matplotlib.dates.date2num(df["month-day"]), df["result"])
plt.xlabel("This axis actually goes from 05-23 to 07-21")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%m - %d"))
plt.show()
```

[image]